# Return from override method from the base method. Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a virtual method in my base class that gets overwritten in an inherited class.

I want to be able to exit both the base virtual method and the overriding method from within the base virtual method.

Using a bool to achieve this does not feel programmatically correct. As bools I thought were mostly used to check something.

```cs
    public virtual bool IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
        if (IsDead) return false;

        aiHealth -=damage;

        if (aiHealth <= 0) {
            Death();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```cs
public override bool IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
        if (!base.IsHit(damage, hitDirection)) return false;

        //Do stuff when enemy is hit.


        return true;
    }
```

Another way I tired which is also not to clean looking is.

```cs
public virtual void IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
        if (IsDead) return;

        aiHealth -=damage;

        if (aiHealth <= 0) {
            Death();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```cs
 public override void IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
        base.IsHit(damage, hitDirection);
        if (IsDead) return;

        //Do stuff.
    }
```

But then I have to call the 'IsDead' check twice.

I would ideally like to have this method as a void and have some line of code in the virtual void call return and stop the code running in the override method.

Or know which one is the most 'Correct' way.

Comment: If `IsHit` should be more of an event it should be named `OnHit` or something alike. `IsHit` is a perfectly good name for a method that could return a boolean

Comment: @Neijwiert I actually did originally have it called OnHit. I changed it becasue I thought it may casue confusion in the readability as the AI can hit something (actually named OnAttack). I thought that people may get confused if it was called OnHit they would think it was when the AI was hitting something else.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin a cat and the best approach depends on many factors.

You can always throw an exception to exit a method and have the exception bubble up to the appropriate position. But you should do that only for error conditions, which does not seem to be the case here.

In my opinion, your second approach can be fine and checking a bool flag (`IsDead`) should normally have no noticeable performance impact. It is also easy to understand when reading the code.

If you want another approach where the overriding method does not have to check you can split the method in the base class like this

```
public void IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
     if (IsDead) return;
     aiHealth -=damage;

     if (aiHealth <= 0) {
         Death();
         return false;
     }
     IsHitWhenNotDead(damage, hitDirection);
}

protected virtual void IsHitWhenNotDead(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
}
```

And in the derived class:

```
protected override void IsHitWhenNotDead(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
     // Do stuff
}
```

Note how the original `IsHit` is no longer `virtual` and cannot be overriden. Instead you override the empty `IsHitWhenNotDead` method, that is only called when appropriate

Comment: This question never came up to me until now...but why do we have to use the try catch block only for error handling? I know it is intended for error handling, but it seems to me that it can be used in Daniel's case also.

Comment: @TestSubject That might be a question on its own, but basically it using exceptions for control flow obfuscates this flow and also has a performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Split out the logic of the function to a seperate protected virtual method that can be overridden

Base class

```
public void IsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
    OnIsHit(damage, hitDirection);
}

protected virtual bool OnIsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection)
    if (IsDead) return false;

    aiHealth -=damage;

    if (aiHealth <= 0) {
        Death();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Derived class

```
public override bool OnIsHit(int damage, Vector3 hitDirection){
    if (!base.IsHit(damage, hitDirection)) return false;

    //Do stuff when enemy is hit.


    return true;
}
```

Now your main function `IsHit` returns a void like you wanted but the internal implementation returns a `bool` to signal to children if it needs to break out of the code early.

Comment: I like this. Very readable. Just means that i'll end up with a buttload more methods in my base class now.